# NetworkManager not managing ethernet device

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I have a fresh install of the Ubuntu 18.04 server image, on which I run `apt install ubuntu-desktop` to get a desktop environment. No matter what I do, NetworkManager refuses to manage the ethernet device. I want this because I want to be able to manage my OpenVPN client from my desktop.

I've tried all the answers in both of these questions to no avail:

- [ubuntu 18.04, nm(Network Manager) is not able to manage network devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036497/ubuntu-18-04-nmnetwork-manager-is-not-able-to-manage-network-devices)
- [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)

I've traced the problem to the file `/run/NetworkManager/conf.d/netplan.conf` which contains the contents:

```
[keyfile]
# devices managed by networkd
unmanaged-devices+=interface-name:enp0s3,
```

If I remove the `unmanaged-devices` line and restart NetworkManager then it works. But since `/run/` is a temporary filesystem, as soon as I reboot my changes are discarded.

I have no idea where this file is coming from, and my googlefu has failed me when it comes to figuring out how to get networkd to not take control of my ethernet port.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a line `managed=false` in your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?

Comment: No I already fixed that to be `managed=true`. But as I understand it, that is only matters if ifupdown is on the system, but Ubuntu Server uses netplan.

Comment: Ah, actually this answer contained the solution for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031956/network-manager-not-working-when-installing-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-ubuntu-18-04-ser?rq=1

Comment: Actually, you should have left /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf alone, not changed /etc/netplan/*.yaml to renderer: NetworkManager, and just edited the .yaml file in /etc/netplan and configured enp0s3 there.

Comment: @Erik status please

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment...

You should undo your changes to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`...

Your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

followed by...

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

**Update #1:**

If you're sticking with NetworkManager... then your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

followed by...

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Comment: If renderer is networkd, wouldn't that prevent NetworkManager from managing the connection?

Comment: @Erik yes, it's EITHER netplan OR NM, but not both. Since you're running a server, probably in a stable and unchanging environment, most servers run with netplan, hence my answer. You're running a server with a GUI added, which is somewhat unusual.

Comment: I'm not running a server, I just happened to have the server iso available when I was spinning up the VM and used it.

Comment: @Erik I updated my answer.